# xss attack - regex or htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, security, xss

To prevent an xss attack, if I use a php regex to block strange characters like `'>` or `;` do I still need to use `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PDO does a very effective job of protecting your queries from XSS attacks.  No need to worry about whether or not you remembered to protect your queries, because it is automatic.  Several other frameworks support this feature as well.

If I'm not using PDO because of a client requirement or the like, I will at the very least build into my connection class an automatic htmlspecialchars function so that I never forget to do it (though this is my least favorite option)

As a UI guy, I always attack my security issues starting on the --front-- end first.  Proper and well-designed front-end validation can stop unintentional issues from even getting to the query in the first place, and they're the most effective UI pattern for reporting problems to the user.  Blocking elements such as `<` or `;` makes sense in most fields, because they just don't fit.  You can't rely on the front end solely, though, because a person could bypass it by turning off javascript.  But, it's a good first step and a great way to limit improper queries on heavily traffic-ed sites.  My validation of choice for quick and effective front-end validation of fields is [here.](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Comment: -1 PDO does *nothing* to protect against XSS. It protects against SQL injection, but not XSS.

Answer (score 2):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) are recommended as protection from XSS attacks over a hand-crafted regex. *But*, you must take into account context. For example, [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will protect dynamic content inside a `<div>` tag but not inside a `<script>` tag or an event handler such as `onclick`. Within html comments, no protection is offered by encoding. The key to writing code that is not vulnerable to XSS attacks is understanding all the different attack vectors.

For the complete details on XSS prevention, I recommend the [OWASP XSS cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Don't use htmlentities() because it will create HTML entities that are not recognized by all browsers.  All you need to do is use htmlspecialchars() and then make sure the encoding is set correctly in your header and meta tag.  Browsers do great job as long as you define your encodings correctly.

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: Can you provide an example of an HTML entity produced by `htmlentities()` and a browser that doesn't recognize it?

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: BTW: both [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) accept an optional `$charset` argument.

Comment: but what is the difference between a good regex expression and what you suggest? why htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() are the best choice?

Comment: @Wire Creation: Why write your own regex-based solution, which you might screw up, when the language includes built-in optimized functions that work?

Comment: sincerely seems to me more efficient, block all strange characters to all of input fields, like name, password, address, and so on.

Comment: @Wire Creation: From a performance perspective, a regex based solution will almost certainly be _less_ efficient than the built-in `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` functions. Regex engines are slow. The implementations of the built-in functions most likely use hashmaps for the mappings which provide constant-time lookups for all the characters that need to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

try use also:

[html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: This does the opposite of what the OP is asking.